# Understanding and finding this DC-DC converter

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc, dc-dc-converter

Reading a circuit, I found the following component:

[image: DC-DC]

It is a simple DC-DC converter. There is no possibility to find a datasheet for it. My two questions are:

1. I understand that VO1 is supposed to be 5V, and VO2, 13,6V, but what does the capital M mean before the 15V in VO3? Does it mean millivolts? I have never seen that before and did not find any information about it.
2. How can I search/find an equivalent IC in the market? I am new to this and do not really know how to search for specific components like this one.

If some context is needed, the DC-DC converter was part of the following power supply:

[image: Power Suplly]

Comment: The capital M is probably for "minus"; i.e., it's -15V out of that pin.

Comment: ...And I would guess that it is Vo rather than VD

Comment: Three outputs of +5 V, -15 V and +13.6 V is not likely an off-the-shelf part. It's at least semi-customized for this application. It's probably a "module" (a little circuit board) of some kind rather than an IC.

Comment: @EugeneSh.,  given there are other D's in the image that don't look like the O's in VO1, VO2, and VO3, you don't even have to guess.

Comment: @ThePhoton My analysis didn't get that far :)

Comment: @ThePhoton I is very likely that it is an external module. However, where can I look for an IC like this and see wether it exists or nor? And, in case I decided to make a module myself, would it be as easy as taking three voltage regulators and soldering their Vin and GND legs?

Comment: @user3141592, no, making a negative voltage from a positive supply requires something more complicated than a linear regulator. There are switching regulators that can do it, and switched capacitor circuits. The switching regulator circuit requires magnetic components (inductors or transformers) that aren't readily integrated on an IC.

Comment: The switched capacitor circuits tend to have fairly low current limits (maybe 100 mA?), especially if the capacitors used are on die.

Comment: And then, isn't it possible to design a simple circuit with an operational amplifier? Are magnetic components really needed?